# return resolved promise and execute the code after resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following code which returns a promise, but also should execute some code:

```
if (fileExists()) {
     return $q.when().then(function () {
         $scope.$broadcast('create-file-success', file);
     });
}
```

I sense that this is not the best way to do that, maybe I should use some thing like that:

```
 return $q.when(function () {
     $scope.$broadcast('create-file-success', file);
 });
```

or like that:

```
 return $q(function () {
     $scope.$broadcast('create-file-success', file);
 });
```

But I can't figure out from the documentation whether the last two do the same.

Comment: So, you want to brodcast an event, and then return a resolved promise? Why don't you do exactly that? broadcast first, then return $q.when()?

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no point in using success callback in such a way after resolve? What if all promises resolve after repaint and I want to broadcast event after that?

Comment: Once you get the promise object from your service, then all you need is to call your function inside your 'then' block

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like following :

```
 $q.when(fileExists()).then(function (data) {
     console.log('Resolved with the value data', data);
     //do whatever you want to do with the resolved object and data.
     $scope.$broadcast('create-file-success', file);
 });
```

I hope this helps :)